# Simple way of porting a MSVC project that use stdafx into xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I often start small projects in MSVC 10 using precompiled headers (seems simpler to me).

Once I want to make the thing compile on XCode (3), I'm screwed, I don't know how apple does precompiled headers compared to microsoft's, I have many errors while compiling, I guess the includes are nesting.

How can I make things easy, not having to edit all my files, or maybe just adding something simple which doesn't break the windows project (using same source files) ?

EDIT: I'm just using SFML (for now)

Comment: Precompiled headers might be the easy part. Is the project using MFC classes by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way VS does precompiled headers is that it detects the precompiled header at the beginning of source files and instead of processing it normally will insert its precompiled version of the header.

Any build system that doesn't do precompiled headers the same way will simply process the headers multiple times and be slower, but otherwise will not get any extra errors as a result of stdafx.h.

Seems like your problem must lay elsewhere.

Comment: Yes you're right, I reinstalled SFML 2.0, works better now. Can't wait for mountain lion so xcode can't complain about for(auto i = a.begin();;)